# What is cron expression for scheduling a daily task with fixed start and fixed end date?

Tags: tasks

I want to schedule a task for this i am creating a cron Expression but  don't know how to create and use cron expression for this task. Requirment is 15 April 2015 to 1 Feb 2016

Comment: What is your time interval between two consecutive iterations of the task?
PS: and by task I suppose you mean a schedulable job right?

Comment: @A-d  time interval is once in a day between 15 April 2015 to 1 Feb 2016

Comment: Well as per salesforce document, 
If IsRecurrence is true, then RecurrenceStartDateOnly, RecurrenceEndDateOnly, RecurrenceType, and any properties associated with the given recurrence type must be populated.
So for your case it should be 
IsRecurrence = true,
RecurrenceType = daily,
RecurrenceStartDate = 15 april 2015
and RecurrenceEnddate = 1 feb 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Task, you want to set `IsRecurrence = True` when you create it (field is read only on update).

Then there are a number of other parameters you'll also want to set depending on what you want your recurrence frequency to look like.

`RecurrenceDayOfMonth` - Integer

`RecurrenceDayOfWeekMask` Integer
The day or days of the week on which the task repeats. This field contains a bitmask.
For each day of the week, the values are as follows:
• Sunday = 1
• Monday = 2
• Tuesday = 4
• Wednesday = 8
• Thursday = 16
• Friday = 32
• Saturday = 64
Multiple days are represented as the sum of their numerical values. For example,
Tuesday and Thursday = 4 + 16 = 20.

`RecurrenceEndDateOnly` - date

`RecurrenceInstance` - picklist
The frequency of the recurring task. For example, “2nd” or “3rd.”

`RecurrenceInterval` - Integer
The interval between recurring tasks

`RecurrenceMonthOfYear` - picklist
The month of the year on which the task repeats.

`RecurrenceStartDateOnly` - date
The date when the recurring task begins. Must be a date and time before `RecurrenceEndDateOnly`.

`RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey`- picklist
The time zone associated with the recurring task. For example, “UTC-8:00” for Pacific Standard Time.

`RecurrenceType` - picklist
Indicates how often the task repeats. For example, daily, weekly, or every nth month
(where “Nth” is defined in `RecurrenceInstance`).

The following table describes the usage of recurrence fields. Each recurrence type must have all of its properties set. All unused properties must be set to null.

[image: Usage of recurrence fields]

For more on this, see the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf).

Comment: thanks for your help but we can't access RecurrenceEndDateOnly these field on the controller so how can i set value into this variable

Comment: If you post your controller code, we can take a look to see if there's something that pop-out as an obvious cause of the problem you're having with accessing it.